# React:webpack 4 -- one chunk not finding the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a bizarre issue happening in my react application, bear with me.

I have a react/flux application that's built with webpack, with multiple entry points and a vendor bundle chunk. I'm working on upgrading to webpack 4, and I'm nearly complete but there's one bug that's driving me crazy.

The page has an entry point for the container components (header, footer, modal, etc), and a different entry point for the components of a specific page. `container.js` contains the Modal store and Modal component, and `page.js` contains the Button component and the Modal Actions file (which dispatches the `modal-triggered` event).

Before upgrading to Webpack 4, this set up worked just fine. After upgrading to Webpack 4, the Button component doesn't trigger the Modal component. The Button dispatches the `modal-triggered` event successfully, but the Modal store doesn't hear it.

I can trigger the Modal component just fine from the header area (which is part of `container.js`).

What's going on here? I can tell from the browser inspector's "sources" tab that all files are loading their components/stores successfully.

Thanks

Comment: if it was redux, I'd assume that different chunks ended up with different stores: button is dispatching an action in one store, modal is bound to another. could it be the case?